# Background color of button disappears after hovering over

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I've been working on a menu bar, and after I set the id to active, I hover over it and the new  color that I set is gone and the menu item reverts back to its original color. Any ideas? 
Here's my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5M2a/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#active').mouseover(function() {
         $(this).css('background-color',  '#CCC');
    });
    $('#active').mouseout(function() {
         $(this).css('background-color',  '#CCC');
    });
    $('.menuOption').mouseover(function() {     
         $(this).css('background-color', '#999999');
    });
    $('.menuOption').mouseout(function() {
         $(this).css('background-color', '#e9e9e9');
     });
 });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="side-bar"> 
                <ul class="side-nav">
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="menuOption" id="active"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="menuOption"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="menuOption"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="menuOption"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                </ul>   
           </div>
```

Comment: And you do this with jQuery instead of CSS because?

Comment: agreed. check out [`:hover`](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/)

Comment: Rearrange your handling (handle `#active` last) and you might see where the problem is: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Z5M2a/3/).

Comment: @putvande, gotcha. Everything worked once I changed it :hover. Wasn't thinking.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `#active` is also a `.menuOption`, and you're explicitly setting the `background-color` of all `.menuOption` elements to a specific background-color on the `mouseout` event, which over-writes the previously set `#active` element's `background-color`.

Re-order your code to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menuOption').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#999999');
    });
    $('.menuOption').mouseout(function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#e9e9e9');
    });
    $('#active').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#CCC');
    });
    $('#active').mouseout(function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#CCC');
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Z5M2a/3/).

And the problem disappears.

Incidentally, to use CSS (which is far more simple), simply add the following rules:

```
#active:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.menuOption:hover {
    background-color: #999;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Z5M2a/6/).

Answer (score 0):

Save Item Color and when mouse out happen, return the original color.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var itemColor;
    $('#active').mouseover(function() {

        $(this).css('background-color',  '#CCC');
    });
    $('#active').mouseout(function() {

        $(this).css('background-color',  itemColor);
    });
    $('.menuOption').mouseover(function() {     
          itemColor = $(this).css('background-color');
        $(this).css('background-color', '#999999');
    });
    $('.menuOption').mouseout(function() {

        $(this).css('background-color', itemColor);
    });
});
```